# CSS editor which expands one-line declarations on editing

Tags: css, editor

Is there a CSS editor which automatically expands one-line declarations as multi-line declarations on focus ? To clarify my thought, see example below:

Original CSS:

```
div#main { color: orange; margin: 1em 0; border: 1px solid black; }
```

But when focusing on it, editor automatically expands it to:

```
div#main { 
  color: orange; 
  margin: 1em 0; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

And when it looses focus, editor again it automatically compresses it to one-line declaration.

Thanks.

Comment: I've never heard of that but that's a good thing to suggest to IDE developers

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Visual Studio you should be able to do a close approximation of this:

1. You can change how CSS is formatted
   via the Tools -> Options menu.
2. Check 'Show all settings' if it is unchecked.
3. Go to Text Editor -> CSS -> Format and pick the semi-expanded option
4. Ok you changes.
5. Then <kbd>ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+D</kbd> should re-format your document
6. When you are finished editing just go back to the options and pick the compact CSS format then <kbd>ctrl+A</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl+K</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl+D</kbd> to re-format again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard of one. If you're on a Mac I can definitely recommend [CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/). It does auto-formatting very nicely, amoungst other things.

EDIT: I originally said "though as the comment says it's a great idea" but, thinking about it, is that what you really want? I can see that it would be good to have expansion/contraction onClick (in which case [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) - again Mac - though CSS suport isn't as good as CSSEdit), but onFocus?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I don't know of any IDEs that explicitly do that.

But, there are quite a few external options:

- [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) (download)
- [Clean CSS](http://www.cleancss.com/) (in-browser)
- [CSS Optimiser](http://floele.flyspray.org/csstidy//css_optimiser.php) (in-browser)
- [others...](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+(tidy+OR+beautify)) (Google Search)

Answer (score 0):

da5id, I actually don't care about implementation details (onclick or onhover, though onclick seems better when you say it ;), I'm just curious if there are any editors which supports this kind of feature in any way.

PS. I'm not on Mac but Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly what you want but try the windows port of textmate [E Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/), for on click folding of css rules, auto formating and most other textmate functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the scripting language of your favorite editor.

For example in SciTE:

```
function ExpandContractCSS()
  local ext = string.lower(props["FileExt"])
  if ext ~= "css" then return end
  local line = GetCurrentLine()
  local newForm
  if string.find(line, "}") then
    -- On one line
    newForm = string.gsub(line, "; *", ";\r\n  ")
    newForm = string.gsub(newForm, "{ *", "{\r\n  ")
    newForm = string.gsub(newForm, " *}", "}")
  else
    -- To contract
    -- Well, just use Ctrl+Z!
    -- Maybe not, code to come if interest
  end
  if newForm ~= nil then
    ReplaceCurrentLine(newForm)
  end
end
```

GetCurrentLine and ReplaceCurrentLine are just convenience functions from my collection, I can give them (and do the contraction part) if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. I'd love to see this in a CSS editor. [TopStyle](http://www.newsgator.com/Individuals/TopStyle/Default.aspx) does this, but it isn't automatic; you have you use a hotkey.