# Convention for CSS Formatting

Tags: css, formatting

Some developers are particular about how they format their codes, for some good reasons. CSS is one of the items whose formatting doesn't really have a strong convention to follow (most probably because of its declarative nature).

Our group typically follow this "convention." The longer and more detailed doc can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YxUHQUnQ8NvMgF8bjdHi8W2WNecvRT9LgwFKXn4yXJU/edit).

```
/* Separate each selector to its own line. */
selector-1,
selector-2<1-space>{
  <indent>property:<1-space>value;
}

selector {
  /* Float. */
  /* Positioning related declarations. */
  /* Visibility. */
  /* Box related declarations. */
  /* Font related declarations. */
}
```

Is there a tool, which I can easily customize, in order to produce this formatting?

Actually, I'd be really interested to gather other experienced CSS programmers' inputs about e.g. whether it's better to lump multiple selectors into one line or separate them into multiple lines, whether I should even bother to prettify and maintain logical orders of my code manually.

**Note:** This probably doesn't perfectly fit to be a SO question. However, I am pretty certain the experience accumulated by some SO-ers during their tenure writing and maintaining CSS codes will definitely give insights to this issue.

Some CSS auto-format tools [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161056/583539) but there are not quite extensible.

Comment: Look into notepad++ for writing css its a good text editor with code hilighting. As far as CSS standards, you wont find anything concrete. Just write code which you as a developer wouldn't mind inheriting and you should be good.

Comment: been reading on the subject myself you may find some insite in this [article](http://css-tricks.com/different-ways-to-format-css/)

Comment: Ouch... closed! Where should I post this type of question?

Comment: Yes! use the "Group" feature of http://procssor.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically follow this convention. Also using only one indent. This allows maximum readability in our team.

```
.selector {
    Style Defs: 
      * dimensions (width, height) styles
        * positioning (with coordinates) styles
        * float/clearstyles
      * spacing (margin, padding, border) styles
        * display/visibility styles
        * typography-related (line-height, color, etc.) styles
        * miscellaneous (list-style, cursors, etc.) styles
}
```

Comment: I was actually looking for something more thorough than this. Accepted because this question had been closed.

Answer (score -1):

I typically split layout style definitions, colour / image style definitions and @media print into to three completely separate stylesheets, which are then combined, minified and cached at view time by a bespoke handler.